# The high road to learn algebraic geometry

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

Suppose that a student has a basic knowledge in commmutative algebra at the level of the Atiyah-MacDonald.

What do you think about the following steps to learn algebraic geometry?

**step 1:** read "Fulton - Algebraic curves: And introduction to algebraic geometry"

**step 2:** take the Hartshorne, skip the first chapter and read directly at least chapters 2 and 3.

Comment: do not skip any chapters of Hartshorne. it is a tough book but very rewarding. also study some extra things like tangent/fiber bundles to get some geometric insight.